# SQL Server Reporting Services Administration Dashboard

Tags: ssrs-2008

We got Reporting Server (SSRS) which has got nearly 100+ reports. Is there any tool available open source or paid which can provide below mentioned stats:

```
Reports By Execution Time (from Execution Log)
Top Reports
Slowest Reports
Reports by User
Optimization Analysis
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you are looking for:

```
    SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(10), ex.TimeStart, 101) AS [Run Date], cat.Name as [Report Name], ex.UserName, ex.Format, ex.TimeStart, ex.Parameters
    FROM ExecutionLogStorage  AS ex WITH(NOLOCK) 
    INNER JOIN
    Catalog AS cat WITH(NOLOCK) ON ex.ReportID = cat.ItemID
    ORDER BY [Run Date] Desc, [Report Name]
```